# How to make 3 level authentication system in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an existing project build with **`Laravel 5.5`**. It has a `USER` login and `Admin` login. Now I want to add a 3rd authentication `AUTHOR` login. I have copy pasted admin files in author folder and edited them replacing admin by author . But it's not working even I added author in **`handle.php`** and `config/auth`.

I don't want to use roles.

Here are my codes:

**Handler.php**

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception) {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }
        $guard = array_get($exception->guards(),0);
        switch ($guard) {
            case 'admin':
                return redirect()->guest(route('admin.login'));
            break;
            default:
                return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
            break;
        }
    }

  protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception) {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }
        $guard = array_get($exception->guards(),0);
        switch ($guard) {
            case 'author':
                return redirect()->guest(route('author.login'));
            break;
            default:
                return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
            break;
        }
    }
```

**Redirectif authenticated**

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated {
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null) {
        switch ($guard) {
            case 'admin':
                if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect('/admin-dashboard');
                }
                break;
            default:
                if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect('/user/dashboard');
                }
                break;
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: "_i don't want to use roles_" Any specific reason for that?

Comment: yes because it is existing project and admin and users are seprate

Comment: You need to use Hesto Multi Auth which is game of a minute https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth

Comment: please can you explain how i can build 3rd panel also